# Removing camera from lockscreen

Tags: ios

Is there a way to remove the camera from the iPhone lock screen on iOS 9-10 without disabling the camera entirely?

Comment: No, is the short answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible without jailbreaking.
If the device is jailbroken, you can use [mikoto](https://cydia.angelxwind.net/?page/net.angelxwind.mikoto): iOS System > Lock Screen > Disable Camera.